# EAuth Extension Yii2, Class nodge\eauth\EAuth does not exist

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to use `EAuth` extension in `Yii2` advanced application. I installed it through `composer` and it installed it under vendor directory and configured as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Nodge/yii2-eauth) (did the config in common/config/main). So, following is the directory structure for that:

```
root
   vendor
        nodege
            lightopenid
                     provider
                          *files go here*
            yii2-eauth
                     src
                       *files go here*
```

`EAuth.php` is under src folder. In controller I have done this in use:

```
use nodge\eauth\EAuth;
```

and when I do this:

```
$eauth = Yii::$app->get('eauth')->getIdentity($serviceName);
```

I get the following error:

> Class nodge\eauth\EAuth does not exist

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

**Update:**

This is my config:

```
'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'eauth' => [
            'class' => 'nodge\eauth\EAuth',
            'popup' => true, // Use the popup window instead of redirecting.
            'cache' => false, // Cache component name or false to disable cache. Defaults to 'cache' on production environments.
            'cacheExpire' => 0, // Cache lifetime. Defaults to 0 - means unlimited.
            'httpClient' => [
// uncomment this to use streams in safe_mode
//'useStreamsFallback' => true,
            ],
            'services' => [// You can change the providers and their classes.
                'google' => [
// register your app here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/
                    'class' => 'nodge\eauth\services\GoogleOAuth2Service',
                    'clientId' => '...',
                    'clientSecret' => '...',
                    'title' => 'Google',
                ],
                'facebook' => [
// register your app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
                    'class' => 'nodge\eauth\services\FacebookOAuth2Service',
                    'clientId' => '---',
                    'clientSecret' => '---',
                ],
                'yahoo' => [
                    'class' => 'nodge\eauth\services\YahooOpenIDService',
                //'realm' => '*.example.org', // your domain, can be with wildcard to authenticate on subdomains.
                ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: could be you must configure the component  .. (take a look a the extension doc)

Comment: I did configure it in common/config/main inside `components` array.

Comment: update you question adding this part of main.php configuration please

Comment: @Saani can you confirm that the file `EAuth.php` is in `root/vendor/nodge/yii2-eauth/src` folder and there is entry `'nodge\\eauth\\' => array($vendorDir . '/nodge/yii2-eauth/src'),` in `root/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`?

Comment: Yes it is inside src folder

Comment: @Saani and the second part?